# Error JSF The prefix "t" for element "t:document" is not bound. Use org.apache.myfaces

Tags: jsf, myfaces

Recently i add the diferent scope code for better performace the jsf livecycle.
Has error in runtime for acess jsf page. What happened?

Web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
     <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ADD_RESOURCE_CLASS</param-name>
     <param-value>org.apache.myfaces.component.html.util.StreamingAddResource</param-value>
</context-param>
```

jsf (xhtml) file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:tjfw="http://tjfw.tjba.jus.br/tjfw/jsf/components/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/main.xhtml">

<ui:define name="contents"
 <f:view>
         <t:document>
         <t:documentHead>
         ...
         <title>example</title>
         ...
         </t:documentHead>
         <t:documentBody>
         ...
         </t:documentBody>
         </t:document>
     </f:view>  

</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Console error:

```
09:40:39,476 FATAL [org.jboss.seam.faces.view.SeamViewMetadata] Error Parsing /resources/pages/objectPearson/pearson.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 188] The prefix "t" for element "t:document" is not bound.
```

Comment: You did not declare the `t` namespace (there is no `xmlns:t="..."` in your JSF). You need to declare this using the appropriate namespace URI.

Comment: Because I received negative feedback on this question?

Comment: I don't know why people vote your question down. But you better get used to that if you ask questions on StackOverflow - it's often not a friendly place for people who ask questions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According with @Jesper

You are trying to acces a library that you didn't declare where to found it.

This 't' is a namespace that you didn't daclare.

Example:
Here you use `<f:view>` and this 'f' is a namespace for this URL :

```
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
```

So you are using a namespace undefined, check out the URL for this namespace 't'

Try this:

```
xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you don't include the library and the assigned prefix (xmlns:t), you can not use it.